# Is there a link between uncountable sets and infinite information?

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers, information-theory

There are only countably many things you can express with a finite number of words. This implies that any uncountable set has to contain uncountably many elements which you cannot define by any finite means. Each of those elements must have an infinite definition that you cannot compress to something finite.

Note that this is not just about countability of computable numbers. Even the most exotic numbers we can think of (e.g. [Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant)) are countable because their definition is finite.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Are you saying that the real numbers don't exist?

Comment: @JohnDouma, heh, well, mostly they admit no description. :)

Comment: The real numbers "admit no description"?!?  Then we're floating in some land of make-believe, devoid of scholarship.

Comment: One issue with this is with the word "description"/"definition". What counts as a valid definition of a number? Consider the following: "The smallest integer not definable in under a million words." Is that a valid definition? If not, what goes wrong?

Comment: @David G.Stork : Merrily, merrily, merrily. It ain't but a dream ;)

Comment: Philosopher Daniel Dennett has a perfect word for such cases:  "deepity"—something that sounds as if it is profound but is actually quite shallow when judged by those with expertise.

Comment: Someone smarter than me wrote this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numb/44129#44129

Comment: Also related: https://karagila.org/2015/name-that-number/

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger thx! He writes "there are probability based algorithms which give an undefinable number as a limit, for example, by throwing dice and writing consecutive numbers after the decimal point". Such an infinite source of randomness is exactly what I mean by (incompressible) infinite information.

Comment: You can describe an uncountable set in a countable way; you only need a countable amount of elements. That contradicts your claim.  Ofcourse countable is infinite here and I am referring to cantor's diagonal.  Also maybe this is more of a linguistic/confusion debate ... just my interpretation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One issue with this is with the word "description"/"definition". What counts as a valid definition of a number? Consider the following: "The smallest positive integer not definable in under a million words." Is that a valid definition? If not, what goes wrong?

Suppose we run Cantor's argument on the definable reals, as follows. List all valid definitions of reals in order of length (use alphabetical order for definitions of the same length). Consider the real whose Nth digit is a 0 if the Nth digit of the Nth definable real is 1, and a 1 otherwise. Is this definable? Have I just defined it? (The issue with this is precisely the same as in my previous comment.) For more, look up the [Berry paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox) and [Richard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard%27s_paradox)…

as well as Wikipedia's page on [definable numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number).

Short resolution is: while we can define increasingly strong notions of definability, there is no *ultimate* notion of definability. If you hand me a definition system, I can create a stronger one that can define more numbers. If $D$ is a definition system, then the phrase "The smallest integer not definable in $D$ under a million words" is not a definition in $D$, but perhaps is a valid definition in a larger system $D'$. Each definition system on its own can only define countably many numbers, though.

Comment: "The concept 'computable' is in a certain definite sense 'absolute', while practically all other familiar metamathematical concepts (e.g. provable, definable, etc.) depend quite essentially on the system to which they are defined." - Gödel

Comment: But the set of definition systems should be countable, too. So even the set of all numbers you can define within any definition system should be countable, no?

Comment: @RobinLinus I'm curious how you justify the set of definition systems being countable.

Comment: The set of anything you can somehow express with a finite number of symbols is countable. So the set of finite definition systems must be countable too. Assuming (incompressible) infinite definition systems just repeats the original question.